# Does the query from the linked server still continue even though you have obtained your result in your SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, openquery

Let's say you have a link server X.

If you were to get 1 row from X in a table (apples) from a schema (fruit). Assuming that the table has a billion rows.

```
Select TOP 1 * from openquery(X , 'SELECT * FROM fruit.apples')
```

Does the query still continue within the openquery statement in the background? or does it terminate once you get that result (SELECT TOP 1)?

Comment: @Dip, What do you mean? when you get the result the query execution is done. why do you think it will still be running on background?

Comment: @DanBracuk, why do you say it continues running?

Comment: @FLICKER I understand you get the result from "SELECT TOP 1" but I am saying within the open query you have "SELECT * FROM fruit.apples". Is that still processing even though you got your result from your end.

Comment: Oh, I see what you saying. why don't you have the top 1 inside the openquery? The question is interesting though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,SQLSERVER quits processing more rows  as soon as first row is returned..

below is simple test query to demonstrate this

```
select top 1* from
openquery(testserver,'select * from performancev3.dbo.orders')
```

Execution plan shows only one row is scanned and returned

[image]

SQLSERVER uses a iterative processing model .So query execution starts from root(Select operator) and it asks top operator to return one row and finally top operator asks the statement below it for one row

Answer (score 0):

This is my test query and observations.

```
select 
--top 1 
*
from openquery(
DW,
'
select *
from visit_fact
where visit_type is not null
'
);
```

DW points to a redbrick database.  It does not handle `is null` or `is not null` very well.  Those queries run slow.  I also have the ability to see the last line of any query currently executing.

The visit_fact table has about 6.5 million rows.

When I run the above query,  results start returning in SSMS instantly, but the information at the bottom shows the query to still be running.  I can also see `where visit_type is not null` when I use something else to see what's running.  It eventually completed in 5 minutes or so.

When I uncomment `top 1`, SSMS instantly shows that the query executed successfully and returned one row.  When I use the other method to see what's running, I see nothing.